# Remove Custom Powershell Object from RAM after adding it to ArrayList?

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I've been fiddling around with a script (written by Vidrine, sourced from http://jfrmilner.rdpress.com/) that catalogs the NTFS permissions of a file server. At the moment it looks through the entire server share and collects permissions only from folders and ignores files. It stores the data in an object and writes it to an array list that is later dumped into a CSV. For reference, the file server is fairly large and has about 7.4TB of data in it. Initially I called an array and wrote to it using the += operator, but the way .net handles arrays made running it on medium sized sub directories a full day event that was extremely memory heavy.

The issue I've run into is that the script is completely memory hungry, and I can't tell if this is simply because of how the script is written, or if it's holding onto objects after writing them to the arraylist. For example, when I run the script against a specific sub directory, rather than the entire server, the script will use roughly 1.4GB of RAM and produces a CSV that's 148MB (100,000 rows x 3 columns). The machine I'm running this on has 16GB of RAM and it still manages to cap out while running against the entire directory.

I've toyed with [void] trying to eliminate $objResults from memory after it's written to $arrResults, but I don't seem to understand how a void cast works. I also attempted to use the [System.GC]::Collect() function, but it just slows down the loop and the accumulation of memory, but doesn't help (this also seems to be a hated practice)

I've tried running it in the Powershell V5 (also V1, V2 and V4) ISE and straight from command line.

Is $objResults staying in memory after being added to $arrResults and is this fixable? Or is the arraylist actually getting up to 15GB in size? 
I'm pretty new to Powershell FYI.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$targetServer    = 'S:\shared data\'    #Enter hostname
$targetDirectory = '' #Enter directory name
$target      = Join-Path -ChildPath $targetDirectory -Path $targetServer
$arrResults      = New-ObjectSystem.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$exportPath  = 'C:\temp\NTFS-OUTPUT.csv' #Enter name of the CSV output file

#Query target directory for all 'folders' (excludes files via Where statement)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $target  | Where { $_.PSIsContainer} |

forEach {

$objPath = $_.FullName
$coLACL  = Get-Acl -Path $objPath 
forEach ( $objACL in $colACL ) {
    forEach ( $accessRight in $objACL.Access ) {        
        $objResults = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
        $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DirectoryPath      –Value $objPath
        $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Identity           –Value $accessRight.IdentityReference
        $objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name SystemRights       –Value $accessRight.FileSystemRights
        #$objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name SystemRightsType   –Value $accessRight.AccessControlType
        #$objResults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsInherited        -Value $accessRight.IsInherited
        #$objResults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InheritanceFlags   -Value $accessRight.InheritanceFlags
        #$objResults | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name RulesProtected     –Value $objACL.AreAccessRulesProtected
        $arrResults.Add($objResults)

         }
     }
}
$arrResults | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $exportPath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No need for the intermediate array: simply output the value and extend the pipeline to Export-Csv.
2. Add-Member is very slow, especially when called many times via pipeline.
   In PowerShell 3.0 and newer you can use a `[PSCustomObject]` accelerator for a literal hashtable.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $target -Directory | ForEach {
    foreach ($objACL in (Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName)) {
        foreach ($accessRight in $objACL.Access ) {        
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DirectoryPath = $_.FullName
                Identity      = $accessRight.IdentityReference
                SystemRights  = $accessRight.FileSystemRights
             }
         }
    }
} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $exportPath
```